# How do I search on a property using Elastic Search for Node.js?

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

I am ingesting various documents to Elastic Search like so:

```
await client.index({
  id: url,
  index: 'docs',
  body: {
    'Url': url,
    'Accessed': new Date().toISOString(),
    'Content': content,
    'Title': title,
  }
});
```

Now, I would like to perform a search on `_source.Title` only. This should be a fuzzy search on English text.

How do I achieve this using the Elastic Search library?

```
  const result = await client.search({
    index: 'docs',
    from: 0,
    size: 20,
    body: {
      "_source": [
        "Url",
        "Title",
        "Accessed",
      ],
      query: {
        // What goes here?
      }
    },
  });
```

I am using `"@elastic/elasticsearch": "^7.4.0"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways to approach the problem. But initially I would use a [`match`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html#query-dsl-match-query-fuzziness) query with fuzziness:

```
  const result = await client.search({
    index: 'docs',
    from: 0,
    size: 20,
    body: {
      "_source": [
        "Url",
        "Title",
        "Accessed",
      ],
      query: {
        "match" : {
          "title" : {
            "query" : "some title terms",
            "fuzziness": 2
          }
        }
      }
    },
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-fuzzy-query.html

```
  const result = await client.search({
    index: 'docs',
    from: 0,
    size: 20,
    body: {
      "_source": [
        "Url",
        "Title",
        "Accessed",
      ],
      query: {
         "fuzzy": {
            "title": {
               "value": "{searchQuery}"
            }
         }
      }
    },
  });
```